# Import a CSV comma-delimited file into a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, sql-server-2016, ssis-2012

I need to import a `.CSV` file into a SQL Server table and I'm having problems due to `"` appearing within the string.

I have found the problem

```
lines ,"32" Leather Bike Trs ",
```

[image]

It never splits the column.

[image]

I've been trying to solve this for hours, what I'm I missing here.

If it can't be done with SSMS Import.

Can it be done in SSIS, import as one big column and use SQL, C# script, what would be my next step to research?

Thanks.

Below sample line to put into a csv file to try.

```
"Company","Customer No","Store No","Store Name","Channel","POS Terminal No","Currency Code","Exchange Rate","Sales Order No","Date of Sales Order","Date of Transaction","Transaction No","Line No","Division Code","Item Category Code","Budget Group Description","Item Description","Item Status","Item Variant Season Code","Item No","Variant Code","Colour Code","Size","Original Price","Price","Quantity","Cost Amount","Net Amount","Value Including Tax","Discount Amount","Original Store No","Original POS Terminal No","Original Trans No","Original Line No","Original Sales Order No","Discount Code","Refund Code","Web Return Description" "Motor City","","561","Outback","In-store","P12301","HKD","1","","","20160218","185","10000","MT","WW","Jeans","32" Leather Bike Trs ","In Stock","9902","K346T4","BK12","BK","12","180.00000000000000000000","149.00000000000000000000","1.00000000000000000000","34.12500000000000000000","135.45000000000000000000","149.00000000000000000000",".00000000000000000000","","","0","0","","","",""
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right the issue come from one `"` placed in your text. The fun fact is, if you had 2 `"` in your text, SSMS could handle it (as many other tools).

Maybe you should consider the possibility to change the text qualifier of your file before implementing a SSIS package ?